# open tooltip on start

Tags: angular, tooltip, ng-bootstrap

How can I open a tooltip from ngboostrap when openeing the compnent.

I tried called the `open` method in the `ngOnInit` function but it didn't show it.

I tried the same method in a button click an that worked 
(based on the sample: https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/app/components/tooltip/demos/tplwithcontext/plnkr.html )

Code:

```
export class TooltipComponent implements OnInit {
    @ViewChild('tleft') public tooltip: NgbTooltip;

    ngOnInit() {
        this.tooltip.open();
    }
}
```

Template:

```
<p>
  <strong ngbTooltip="Tooltip on left" #tleft="ngbTooltip" triggers="manual">Tooltip is here</strong>?
</p>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" (click)="open()">
  Open
</button>
```

Comment: try calling from `ngAfterViewInit` hook, the DOM might not be ready in `ngOnInit`

Comment: @Maximus I think you should write it as answer because it looks like the right solution

Comment: @Maximus yes it is, I accept it when you write it as answer. Thanks

Comment: posted as an answer, thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be calling `this.tooltip.open();` inside `ngAfterViewInit` hook,  not `ngOnInit`. The DOM might not be ready in `ngOnInit`. So, the solution is:

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.tooltip.open();
}
```